# MHTML iFrame overlapping header

Tags: html, iframe, mhtml

I'm trying to embed a MHTML page into a iFrame into a HTML page with headers, but I'm getting overlapping. I tried to change the z-index but it doesn't seem to work. Tried a few other things, but no go, it keeps going on top of the header. Google doesn't give too many fixes for my problem, more for video players by changing the wmode, but that doesn't seem to work for my page. Seems the content scrolls behind the header, but not the iframe contents.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoQvG.png

Chrome does it correctly, IE does not, oddly.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/kNwAk/

```
<iframe src="VSM_Graphic.mhtml?wmode=opaque" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" width="80%" height="100%">iframe not supported!</iframe>
```

Might look a little weird because it's on our intranet.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<iframe src="blahblab" style="position:relative; top:-200px;"></iframe>`

Change the "top" amount to get it where you want it.

Comment: It moves it down, but when I scroll, it still overlaps.

Comment: You need to post a JSFiddle of your code so people can attempt to fix it without just guessing.